# Is there any way to migrate data between different versions?

Tags: database, cnosdb

When I pull the latest code from github for use, the previous version of cnosdb data cannot be reloaded. It looks like a compatibility issue. Is there any way to migrate data quickly and concisely? The only thing I can think of for the moment is COPY OUT & COPY INTO.